# julia Match.jl match error with Date - pattern expects 3 fields

Tags: julia, match

Just updated my project deps and am getting this error with a Match.jl @match statement.

```
ERROR: The type `Dates.Date` has 1 fields but the pattern expects 3 fields.
    
@match date begin
    Date(2023, 4, 10) => true # Monday after Easter
    Date(2023, 5, 1) => true # May Day?
end

Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:35
  [2] bind_pattern!(location::LineNumberNode, source::Expr, input::Symbol, binder::Match.BinderContext, assigned::Base.ImmutableDict{Symbol, Symbol})
    @ Match ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/binding.jl:244
  [3] bind_case(case_number::Int64, location::LineNumberNode, case::Expr, predeclared_temps::Vector{Any}, binder::Match.BinderContext)
    @ Match ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/binding.jl:580
  [4] build_automaton_core(value::Symbol, source_cases::Vector{Any}, location::LineNumberNode, predeclared_temps::Vector{Any}, binder::Match.BinderContext)
    @ Match ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/match_cases_opt.jl:15
  [5] build_automaton(location::LineNumberNode, mod::Module, value::Any, body::Expr)
    @ Match ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/match_cases_opt.jl:149
  [6] build_deduplicated_automaton
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/match_cases_opt.jl:158 [inlined]
  [7] handle_match_cases(location::LineNumberNode, mod::Module, value::Symbol, body::Expr)
    @ Match ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/match_cases_opt.jl:477
  [8] var"@match"(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, value::Any, cases::Any)
    @ Match ~/.julia/packages/Match/SZDEk/src/matchmacro.jl:114
  [9] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:457
 [10] include(x::String)
    @ Main.Tibra ~/src/tibra/Tibra.jl/src/Tibra.jl:1
 [11] top-level scope
    @ ~/src/tibra/Tibra.jl/src/Tibra.jl:101
 [12] include(fname::String)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:478
 [13] top-level scope
    @ ~/src/tibra/Tibra.jl/scripts/run_tibrax_server.jl:1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Interpolate the `Date` functions in the pattern:

```
using Match, Dates

date = Date(2023, 5, 1)

check = @match date begin
    $(Date(2023, 4, 10)) => true
    $(Date(2023, 5, 1)) => false
end

@assert check == false
```

Or you can use the internal constructor `Date(::Dates.UTInstant{Day})` for the patterns:

```
date = Date(2023, 4, 10)

check = @match date begin
    Date(Dates.UTInstant(Day(738620)) => true
    Date(Dates.UTInstant(Day(738642)) => false
end

@assert check == true
```

## Long answer

For the [multi-case `@match` macro](https://juliaservices.github.io/Match.jl/stable/#Multi-case-@match-macro), Match.jl requires the pattern to be one of the following:

- A value
- A regular expression
- A type check or *constructor*
- A Tuple
- An Array

Match.jl only considers constructor functions with the same number of arguments as struct members to be "constructors" in this definition. It does not consider an ["outer constructor method"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-outer-constructor-methods) to be a constructor, which is [what `Date(y, m, d)` is](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/8b8da91ad7701c5401947a749399720f5aa51418/stdlib/Dates/src/types.jl#L255). You can check the workings of the macro yourself by creating a type that has two constructors: one that has the same number of arguments as struct parameters, and one that either has some other number of arguments or arguments with some incompatible types, and `@match` will throw similar exceptions:

```
struct Foo
    a::Int
    b::Int
end

Foo(x::String, y::String) = Foo(parse(Int, x), parse(Int, y))
Foo(x::Int) = Foo(x, 0)

foo = Foo(1, 0)

check = @match foo begin
    Foo(1) => true
    Foo(2) => false
end  # throws LoadError because the number of arguments does not match the number of struct parameters

check = @match foo begin
    Foo("1", "0") => true
    Foo("2", "0") => false
end  # throws MatchFailure, even though Foo(::String, ::String) has the right number of arguments and returns an appropriate Foo struct

check = @match foo begin
    Foo(1, 0) => true
    Foo(2, 0) => false
end

@assert check == true  # works
```

However, you can get around this by simply interpolating the return value of the outer constructor method within the `@match` macro, [as explained in the documentation](https://juliaservices.github.io/Match.jl/stable/#Match-Values):

```
check = @match foo begin
    $(Foo(1)) => true  # interpolates to Foo(1, 0)
    $(Foo("2", "0")) => false  # interpolates to Foo(2, 0)
end

@assert check == true
```

Of course, you could always do this:

```
check = let
    if foo == Foo(1)
        true
    elseif foo == Foo(2)
        false
    end
end

@assert check == true
```

This is basically what the `@match` macro ends up doing for you anyway.